# @media print doesn't print current page

Tags: html, css, sass

I have two  components

```
<div id="div1">
  div1 content
</div>
<div id="div2">
  div2 content
</div>
```

and the style is:

```
#div1{
  height: 1000px;
}

@media print {
  #div1{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

so when I scroll to very bottom (few pages to div2) and try to print Ctrl+P then it doesn't show div2 on print page but just blank one (assume just first blank page that was hidden but no div2). How that can be fixed? Thank you

Comment: When you print, it doesn't print whatever scroll position you are at, it just prints the whole page, you can set page range in the print options but if there are only 2 divs on your page and you hid the first div, then the only print content you will see is div2. your code as you have it now, should work 100%

Comment: it is not shown on Print Preview that may confuse users. So print preview shows only one page that is blank

Comment: Print preview aside, does the printed version show div2 content?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way:

```
#div2 {
    position: relative;
  }
```